# What is the filesystem used to mount a LUN disk?

Tags: linux, lun

How do you mount a fresh LUN disk to your / ?

Do you use ext3 or NFS for this ?

Answer (score 5):

Neither nor. You use ISCSI or the corresponding SAN protocols for Fibre channel. You then see the disc like a local (unformatted) disc and it is up to you to format it however you like it.

A LUN disc basically is a physical disc (for your operating system) that just happens not to be physically attached to the computer.

As such, mounting a fresh LUN to / is not possible - it is not formatted.

Comment: Just a clarification - a LUN doesn't necessarily have to be remote. LUNs were around *long* before FC/iSCSI remote storage became available.

Answer (score 2):

By "fresh LUN" it sounds like it's a newly created and attached block device with no file-system already on it.

First, you can verify that the device is connected to your host and that it has a device name that you can use to reference it.  There are several different ways, for example using 'fdisk -l' or possibly 'lsscsi' if it's an iSCSI device.

Once you have the correct device name, say */dev/sdd1*, then you can create your favorite file-system on it as any other local block device or disk.